# How to reduce list down to a single option value

Tags: refactoring, sml

I'm having a little trouble rewriting a method to use a higher-order function. Here's the attempt (<s>it compiles but doesn't run</s> it works fine):

```
fun lookup2 key hash = 
  List.foldr (fn ((k, v), r) => if k = key then SOME v else r) NONE hash;
```

---

Background:

The idea is that there is a hash like so and I'm lookup up an int option by string key:

```
- val h = [("a", 5), ("b", 4)];
- lookup "a" h;
val it = SOME 5 : int option
```

I wrote one that works just fine:

```
fun lookup _ nil = NONE
  | lookup key ((k, v)::xs) = if k = key then SOME v else lookup key xs;
```

However I wanted to rewrite it to help get familiar with sml. I have a sneaking suspicion I don't quite understand `foldr`...

---

**My mistake** - I was accidentally overwriting it with a different `lookup2`. It works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is not `List.foldr`, but `List.find`:

> find f l
>
> > applies f to each element x of the list l, from left to right, until x evaluates to true. It returns SOME(x) if such an x exists; otherwise it returns NONE.
>
> ([source](http://www.standardml.org/Basis/list.html#SIG%3aLIST.find%3aVAL))

Now you can do the following:

```
fun lookup key hash = Option.map (fn (_,v) => v)
  ( List.find (fn (k,_) => k = key) hash );
```

Where `List.find` returns the matching tuple `(key, val)` or `NONE`, and `Option.map` returns either `val` from the tuple or also `NONE`.

Comment: @AJcodez: Heh, I liked the version that used the function composition operator (`o`) better! But I have to admit this one might be clearer.

Comment: ah sorry, I didn't recognize it and copy/paste didn't work on my machine. Feel free to change it back :)